# pdfcreator and ghostscript : create PDF with text not compressed

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript, pdfcreator

We are using PDFcreator 2.3.2.
It installs and calls Ghostscript 9.11 to create the PDF output.

We have to create PDFs with inside text not compressed.

The text inside the PDFs must be ASCII or Unicode, searchable from every software ( also Wordpad ) without special plugins / addons.

It is possible to specify additional ghostscript options, but I cannot find the right one.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pdfforge\PDFCreator\Settings\ConversionProfiles\4\Ghostscript]
"AdditionalGsParameters"=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago I stopped upgrading PDFCreator because the newer versions (at the time) had no `Compress Text Objects` option that can be turned off. I don't know whether the current version has the option or not.

The version 1.7.1 has the option for sure: `Options` -> `Format` -> `PDF` -> `Compression` -> `Compress Text Objects`.

Comment: thks for the answer but we cannot downgrade

Comment: Kamil, I can upvote you if you find where the GUI option is written in the registry, and its value. So I can try to set the same option with our version.